# Multiplying a Component's Height Value with Fractional Number Higher than One

Tags: apache-flex, height, custom-component

I'm creating a component and I want to set it's height depending on it's content. When I write this:

```
<s:SkinnablePopUpContainer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                           xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
                           backgroundAlpha="0" 
                           height="{content.height}">
```

It's working as it must but when I want to make my component's height a little more than it's content's height like this:

```
<s:SkinnablePopUpContainer xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                               xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
                               backgroundAlpha="0" 
                               height="{content.height * 3/2}">
```

My component's height becoming something crazy like "3571428.5714285714". But when I do this:

```
height="{content.height * 2/3}"
```

It is just making it's height a little less and working normally.

And when I do it in the creationComplete event, it's still working normally:

```
protected function creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
{
    this.height = content.height * 3/2;
}
```

I want to know if I am doing something wrong.
Thanks for help

Comment: Generally as a rule in the Flex Framework a component is always sized by its parent.  When you set the height in the way you are; really it is just making a suggestion to the parent container.  The default Flex layouts will do their best to honor the numbers you suggest; but it is not guaranteed.  Your best bet is going to be to implement a measure() method that sizes the component based on its children.

Comment: What Flextras said... but something else must be going on in your case. To get "3571428.5714285714" as the result of dividing something by two seems odd. If you do a simple example as you've shown above it behaves as expected. Maybe you can show more of your code (for example, what is `content`, have you specified a layout inside the pop up container, etc.)